# Running arp command on public wifi network

Tags: network

I accidentally ran this `arp -a` on a public wifi network(because it is in my terminal history). I killed the process almost immediately. I want to know if this would raise an alert for the network administrator as I do not want any trouble. Will this be considered as arp spoofing? Will this be regarded as a malicious attempt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have nothing to worry about. The `arp -a` command you ran would simply list the [ARP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) cache tables on your local machine's interface(s) as explained on [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/arp.mspx?mfr=true)'s documentation site.

In order for your machine to communicate with other hosts *on the same, internal network,* [MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) addresses are needed. Each interface should have an [IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ip_address) and MAC address. An ARP table is used to convert a machine's IP to its MAC address.

[ARP Spoofing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP_spoofing) would require a bit more work to do, and by just running `arp -a` you are not sending anything onto the network that would put you into trouble.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. Just out of curiosity: When I ran this command on my home network, the table was displayed instantaneously, but this time nothing had shown up before I killed it. Is this due to the large size of the table in a public wifi network?

Comment: @user30673 My pleasure. That is interesting... I never experience such a delay. I guess depending on your machine's speed and the amount of entries on the cache this could create a slight delay, depending on how long it took you to kill the process. Nothing stops you from flushing the cache and have a new list being built from the scratch. The way to do this depends on your Operating System, though.

Comment: Seeing the delay also furthered my fear. I was afraid that my OS was sending out a barrage of network requests, raising flags.

Comment: @user30673 I feel you fear, and I believe you do well in asking. It is good to know that more people are becoming security-aware.

Answer (score 1):

`arp -a` is merely printing the contents of your existing ARP table in a "BSD style" output. That most definitely will not raise any flags.